# ChangeListener on multiple Properties

Tags: javafx

I have a model Tree of different POJOs containing several JavaFX `Property<?>` properties.

I was now wondering on how to attach a `ChangeListener` to the top of the tree which is fired every time something in the object tree changes.

I experimented a lot with custom Bindings and Invalidations but I think I am missing something here.

The background here is, that I want to detect if the model needs to be saved or not. And I do not want to attach a change listener to every single property in that tree. There must be a better way.

Comment: assuming those property changes notify the TreeItem you only need a TreeModificationEvent handler on the root - changes are auto-propagated up the tree

Comment: hmm .. looks like there is no built-in support for listening to properties of the value. Way out might be a custom TreeItem that can be configured with a listener to properties of its value which fires a valueChanged modification event. Depends on your context, please add details, best as [mcve]

Comment: What about adding all the tree nodes to an [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) and listening for changes to that list?

Comment: ChangeListeners are going to be a beast to deal with.  I'd recommend looking into the DirtyFX libary: https://github.com/thomasnield/DirtyFX